# HSQLDB with multiple backing csv files

Tags: java, csv, jdbc, hsqldb

I need to bind a group of csv file in the format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.csv" that are present in the same folder with a unique table that contains all the data present in all the files.

I found how to bind one file but not how to bind multiple files, for example reading from [here](http://www.trigent.com/blog/handling-csv-files/) or [here](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=23260) but I couldn't find anything about multiple backing files.

Comment: Why not bind each file to one table, then create a view that does a `union all` over the files?

Comment: Because the files are created asynchronously without being under my control and I do not know when a file is added. And their name changes without a precise frequency even if they have a pattern. Your suggestion could be good if the files are static but unfortunately they are dynamically created by another piece of software that I do not own nor control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind multiple files to one table. All the options for TEXT tables are documented here: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/texttables-chapt.html

You can use separate tables. As you say the file names can change, you can write some Java code to periodically list the files in the directory and link the TEXT tables to the more recent files. See the `SET TABLE T SOURCE ...` statement.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's an answer I would not want to read but at least it tells me I need to find another way to do the job. I think it could be a solving answer even if there isn't an answer to my problem.